# Python inheritence issue {RuntimeError}maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, I saw many threads regarding to "maximum recursion depth exceeded" couldn't find in any of them a solution for my issue.

I'm learning Python these days and trying to understand the following issue:
assume we have two classes:

```
class MongoDbAccess:

    def __init__(self, conn_string, db_name, username=None, password=None):
        self.conn_string = conn_string
        self.db_name = db_name

        if username is not None:
            self.auth_mode = True
            self.username = username
            if password is None:
                raise ('Password is missing')
            self.password = password
        else:
            self.auth_mode = False

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def database_name(self):
        return self.db_name
```

and a child class:

```
class MongoDbReporter(MongoDbAccess):
    SUCCESS = 'Success'
    FAILURE = 'Failure'

    def __init__(self, conn_string, db_name, username=None, password=None):
        super().__init__(conn_string, db_name, username, password)
        self.periodic_jobs_coll_name = 'PeriodicJobs'
        self.logs_coll_name = 'Logs'

    @property
    def periodic_jobs_collection_name(self):
        return self.periodic_jobs_coll_name

    @periodic_jobs_collection_name.setter
    def periodic_jobs_collection_name(self, value):
        self.periodic_jobs_coll_name = value
```

While instantiating MongoDbReporter instance

```
mongo_reporter = mongodb.MongoDbReporter('a','a','a','a')
```

the following exception is raised:
[image: exception]

Probably I created some recursion here but I can't find it,
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your property

```
@property
def username(self):
    return self.username
```

you have created an infinite recursion. `self.username` in the return statement calls the property method again, and again…

Remove the whole property from your code and it will work. Python does not need explicid accessors.

Answer (score 2):

change property name(if you need property, here no need of it to define.Because you have an instance variable `username`), Because you have created a `instance variable` with same name.

```
@property
def myusername(self):
    return self.username
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.username = username 

@property
def username(self):
    return self.username
```

Your are causing a race condition by returning a call to the method `username()`

You call the method, it returns the method which is then called again *ad infinitum*